# WPF ContextMenu - no String with ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, datatemplate, itemtemplate

Hi I am new to WPF Development and run into a problem Regarding Binding al public variable to a TextBlock element.

```
<ListBox.ContextMenu>
   <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ActionsView}">
      <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>                                
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
          </DataTemplate>
      </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>    
   </ContextMenu>
```

Action View is a public Observable collection of Action Items each holds a name which is public accessible as Name. So normally there should be no Problem. If I am right clicking on my Item, I get an empty ContextMenu with the correct number of entry’s but without any text.

[picture of the empty ContextMenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffBi6.png)

```
public class Action : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name;        

    public ContextAction(string name)
    {
        Name = name;            
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

It would be really nice if somebody could help me with this problem.

Comment: As far as i know, the binding engine wont work on public fields. Try adding getters and setters.

Comment: Yeah that was the whole Problem with getters and setters everthing is fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was setting the getters an setters that’s it :)

```
 public class ContextAction : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string _name;   

    public ContextAction(string name)
    {
        _name = name;            
    }


    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement property, not a field for bindings to work. Like this:

```
public string Name { get; set };
```